# What would happen memory-wise if I call millions of class methods in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, oop, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, class-method

I know that class methods in Objective-C get loaded once in memory and stay until the app terminates. I am wondering what this means in terms of performance, in comparison to instance methods.

Question 1.

If I call lots of class methods in my code (say millions of class methods), would this effectively load all of them in memory so that they would never go away?

This feels like a problem compared to if I instead implemented them as instance methods, and only instantiate the class locally whenever I need to access them, which then will be garbage collected later when it goes out of scope.

Question 2

What happens to the local variables inside class methods? Do they get garbage collected after each execution? For example I could create millions of local NSObjects inside a class method. Will they get garbage collected once the method returns?

Comment: Are you talking about calling one class method a million times or are talking about implementing a million class methods and calling each of them once?

Comment: FYI - there is no garbage collection in iOS.

Comment: @rmaddy For the first question, I'm talking about implementing a million class methods and calling each of them once. For the second question I guess it's an independent issue--it's more about what happens to millions of local variables created inside a class method

Comment: 1) How are you going to write a million class methods? That's a lot of typing. 2) Code is code. It doesn't matter whether the methods are class or instance methods for the purpose of this question.

Comment: @rmaddy maybe I should have said ARC instead. Regardless, you get the point. I basically want to know the performance implications of class methods in these scenarios...

Comment: @rmaddy it's a hypothetical scenario, but maybe I should have come up with a better way to ask this question. I just want to know when it can be bad to use class methods performance-wise. I am trying to create a bunch of stateless classes, so was curious about edge cases.

Comment: Rule #1 - avoid premature optimizations. Write your code. Worry about performance / memory usage when it's a problem.

Comment: @rmaddy I totally agree with you. As for the first question, I will probably go with writing 100% stateless classes with only class methods, but I am still curious what would happen... As for your comment on the second question, did you mean these millions of NSObjects inside the class method will be automatically released when it returns? I know it may sound stupid but just making sure!

Comment: ARC will of course take care of local variables in any method, function, or other scope that you care to invent; class methods are no different. For the memory of the methods themselves, the code must already be part of your program for you to call them at all. The runtime does cache implementations to make repeated calls to the same method faster, but that takes a constant amount of memory. I'm not sure whether class method implementations are cached or not.

Comment: As you knew about the arc works here, local variables loaded inside the stack memory which are soon releases as they are no longer to use in a program Whereas the objects are loaded into heap memory so they needs some assistance like mrc or arc.